# Partitioning a NumPy array based on labels

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have  data sets A and B.
A is a matrix which shape is [169594, 22]
B is a matrix which shape is [169594,1]
B consists of (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) which is the label of each row of A.

So, I would like to separate Data of A into each labels.

So my code is as below.

[image]

I am beginner in Python, so this code is not work.

If this code is work well, the expected result is as below.

```
aa[xxx, 22]
bb[xxx, 22]
cc[xxx, 22]
dd[xxx, 22]
ee[xxx, 22]
ff[xxx, 22]
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: why did you take a picture of your code instead of pasting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reshape `B` into a 1D array and then use `boolean indexing` on `A`.

```
B = B.reshape(-1, )
aa = A[B == 0, :]
bb = A[B == 1, :]
cc = A[B == 2, :]
dd = A[B == 3, :]
ee = A[B == 4, :]
ff = A[B == 5, :]
```

Or, even better, keep segregated items in a list.

```
l = []
for i in range(6):
    l.append(A[B == i, :]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: I have one more question. how can I combine matrix aa and bb? If shape of  aa and bb is [100, 22], I want to make sum=aa+bb=shape[200, 22]. Thank you!

Comment: @Tom `np.vstack((aa, bb))`